# Compute expression length without computing expression itself

Tags: algorithm, math, formula

I need to compute complex expression decimal length (contains factorials) without computing expression itself.
For example: 
Decimal length of `( 400! / ( 100! * 300!) )`
Any methods that may do the task or math formulas may be useful.
Thank you.

Comment: Is an approximation good enough?

Comment: Indeed, with the Stirling approximation, one can approximate quite descently.

Comment: This is where the lngamma function is so useful.  I'd look into that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If an **approximation is sufficient**, we can use the *Stirling approximation*:

n! ~ sqrt(2×πn)×(n/e)<sup>n</sup>

This result is not very interesting for our goal directly, but we can use the log10 to obtain the number of digits:

log<sub>10</sub>(n!) ~ log<sub>10</sub>(sqrt(2×πn))+n×log<sub>10</sub>(n/e)

Now we can calculate the number of digits of a!/(b!×c!), by using:

log(a!/(b!×c!)) = log(a!)-log(b!)-log(c!)

which is equal to:

log(a!/(b!×c!)) = log<sub>10</sub>(sqrt(2×πa))+a×log<sub>10</sub>(a/e)-log<sub>10</sub>(sqrt(2×πb))-b×log<sub>10</sub>(b/e)-log<sub>10</sub>(sqrt(2×πc))-c×log<sub>10</sub>(c/e)

And the number of digits of a number *n* is roughly ⌊log(n)⌋+1.

So for instance in Python we can *approximate*:

```
from math import log10, pi, e, sqrt, floor

def approx_fac_log10(n):
    return log10(sqrt(2.0*pi*n))+n*log10(n/e)

def approx_length(a,b,c):
    return 1+floor(approx_fac_log10(a)-approx_fac_log10(b)-approx_fac_log10(c))
```

For your formula we then obtain:

```
>>> approx_length(400,100,300)
97
```

If we calculate the result, we get:

```
>>> factorial(400)//(factorial(100)*factorial(300))
2241854791554337561923210387201698554845411177476295990399942258896013007429693894018935107174320
>>> factorial(400)/(factorial(100)*factorial(300))
2.2418547915543375e+96
```

If we convert the result to a string, and then obtain the length of that string, we get:

```
>>> len(str(factorial(400)//(factorial(100)*factorial(300))))
97
```

So the approximation was correct: the result has indeed 97 digits.

You can improve the quality of the approximation by using the *more* terms in the *Stirling approximation*. Eventually if you take an infinite amount of terms, you will indeed calculate the result exactly:

[image: approximation]

Answer (score 0):

The number of digits in a number x is floor(log(x)) + 1:
[a proof on math.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/231742/proof-how-many-digits-does-a-number-have-lfloor-log-10-n-rfloor-1)

So, depending on your efficiency needs a simple approach of adding and subtracting logarithms might be enough.